# CR2450 Battery at 2.95 Volts

Tags: batteries

If the open circuit voltage of a 3V CR2450 Battery is at 2.95 Volts: is it at end of life?

I have a CR2032 3V that could fit in the device and I could use a nickel to compensate to fill the gap in the device: is there any foreseeable problem in doing this?

Update: installed a CR2032 as a temporary measure until  a CR2450 can be shipped.  Seems to work well.  CR2032 are 2 for $1 at the dollar store vs $7 for a CR2450 at CVS

Comment: Datasheet says?

Comment: Charge condition may be possible to estimate from datasheet curves, with a specified load applied as specified in the datasheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For CR2450 with a capacity of  >600mAh at a 0.4mA rate;

If ESR is < 20 Ohms then you have at least 50% capacity left.
If ESR is > 50 Ohms then there is not much life left (20%?)

Use a 1K load and measure voltage before after and compute voltage drop in % and multiply percent of 1K as your ESR.

- Capacity drops with a load < 100*ESR and rapidly with < 50*ESR
- Capacity increases with load resistance up to ~1000* ESR

Based on Voc=2.95V or -0.05V from 3.0V, I estimate it is at 90% SoC

Using a Nickel spacer will work but obviously it will not last as long as a thicker CR2477 Lithium cell with up 1000mAh.

Comment: Good to hear from you again Tony.  Thanks for the explanation

Comment: Thanks @gatorback , let me know how close my calculations are when you get a chance

Answer (score 1):

I have a MyQ garage door sensor it says replace on my phone the new CR2450 3.380 volts the one I am replacing reads 2.980.I will be installing a AA battery pack next to it with 2 AA lithium batteries so the batteries don't have to be replaced as often

Comment: Please consider posting a photo of the final assembly.  How often do you have to replace the battery?Thanks